# python pyinotify event from externally created file

Tags: python, inotify, network-drive

I have a pyinotify instance watching a mounted network drive **(mounted with CIFS)** for IN_WRITE_CLOSE events which picks up the system created events (sudo cp, sudo mv, etc.) flawlessly if the server itself puts files in this directory.

However, I would like to pick up the events for files that are created on this network drive by a different server and program.

For some reason my inotify instance is not seeing these events...Is this normal behavior or could there be something wrong with my code? If this **IS** normal behavior, is there a way around it or do I have to find a different monitoring tool other than inotify to gather these events?

**UPDATE**

per @Cedric's answer I changed my mountpoint to NFS but I am still not getting any events.

Comment: what kind of network mounting are you using ? NFS, CIFS ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://lists.samba.org/archive/linux-cifs-client/2009-April/004318.html) on the linux cifs client, this wasn't implemented (nor really scheduled) in 2009.

For the NFS part, well, it works on NFS mount, but only if the listener is the same machine than the creater/modifer/deleter of the file.... :( ([source here](https://serverfault.com/a/3450/81503))

Last, I ended by founding a hook ([just here](http://pastebin.com/RNuc0xeJ)), this is a python script that you have to run on the remote server that will send to you the events (the script is made to talk to a MediaTomb server on http, but you can implement your own sender)

Comment: @sadmicrowave : it seems that the answer is "YES, unfortunately?"

Comment: thats not really a problem (in this case) since my network drive is also NFS mountable.  I'm just getting a 'permissions denied' error right now and I'm trying to figure that out.  Do you know of an error log where mounting errors are sent on *nix OS (ubuntu)

Comment: @sadmicrowave : should be in `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: I finally got my NFS to mount properly but the pyinotify instance still is not finding the events when files are created by another server program.  I even changed the event handler to ALL_EVENTS but nothing is being found...

Comment: @sadmicrowave : well, it works on NFS mount, but only if the listener is the same machine than the creater/modifer/deleter of the file....I edited my answer with my last search results.